# Как научить Eclips создавать JavaFX Script Application проекты?

Tags: java, eclipse, javafx

Нашел инфу только для NetBeans (`File->New Project->JavaFX-> JavaFX Script Application`).

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Установил плагин `e(fx)clipse 2.4.0`, но он все равно не позволяет создавать JavaFX Script Application, только просто JavaFX Project.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Мне нужно чтобы Eclips умел создавать и видел файлы в формате (.fx). В общем прошу помощи, сам уже перерыл в инете все что мог.

Comment: Может быть я отстал, но вроде это было же очень давно, не так ли? Не проще сейчас делать .fxml файлы?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Насколько я знаю - никак.По своей сути та технология к которой вы ссылаетесь отпала где то с версией Fx 2.2 по моему...Ну и если быть совсем точным то не отпала а видоизменилась. Конечно для построения UI сейчас чаще используется FXML файл и строение объектов по дереву описанному в нем.для веб разработки не самый простой вариант) Нагуглить примеры дело простое.Еще один способ - скриптовые файлы интерпретированные скриптовым движком Nashorn. Действительно мощный инструмент в умелых руках.Вызов

> jjs -fx test.js

на примере:

```
load("fx:base.js");
load("fx:controls.js");
load("fx:graphics.js");

var material = new PhongMaterial();
material.diffuseColor = Color.LIGHTGREEN;
material.specularColor = Color.rgb(30, 30, 30);

var meshView = Java.to([
    new Box(200, 200, 200),
    new Sphere(100),
    new Cylinder(100, 200)
], "javafx.scene.shape.Shape3D[]");

for (var i = 0; i != 3; i++) {
    meshView[i].material = material;
    meshView[i].translateX = (i + 1) * 220;
    meshView[i].translateY = 200;
    meshView[i].translateZ = 20;
    meshView[i].drawMode = DrawMode.FILL;
    meshView[i].cullFace = CullFace.BACK;
};

var pointLight = new PointLight(Color.WHITE);
pointLight.translateX = 800;
pointLight.translateY = -200;
pointLight.translateZ = -1000;

var root = new Group(meshView);
root.children.add(pointLight);

var scene = new Scene(root, 800, 400, true);
scene.fill = Color.rgb(127, 127, 127);
scene.camera = new PerspectiveCamera(false);
$STAGE.scene = scene;
$STAGE.show();
```

вернет Вам отличную 3Д систему. Ну а о перспективах и возможностях представлять объекты Java как элементы скриптового языка и говорить не стоит.Есть еще как минимум один вариант о котором стоит упомянуть -> построение UI с помощью fxgraph системы (инструмент поставляется с плагином e(fx)clipse 2.4.0) при создании FX проекта выберете соответствующий пункт меню[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
и вуаля простой синтаксис самостоятельная генерация fxml и т.п

пример синтаксиса

```
package application

import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane
import javafx.scene.control.Button
import application.SampleController

component Sample controlledby SampleController {
    BorderPane {
        center : Button {
            text : "Hello World"
        }
    }
}
```